# App with no content - appStore review

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, review

I am preparing my app for AppStore review.
App is supposed to display products of specific company, customise them and send to sales department.
The app by default does not store any data and one has to download it. Access to this data will be restricted for sales department employees only (user/pass administrated on server).

I've read the guidelines, but didn't found my answer: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Is it possible to get to appstore with app, that does not have any content until password is given?
I can create user for apple review team and then they'll get the content.

Comment: The app doesn't sound suitable for the app store; sounds like you should be using an enterprise ad-hoc release mechanism.

Comment: No i don't think it would be a problem. Give it a try. And if this app is meant for specific company's employee then you should check the enterprise distribution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question about policy compliance, not about programming as defined by the [help]. Legal questions can be asked on https://law.stackexchange.com/, instead. Questions about Apple policy should be directed to Apple support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide demo account details:

- in iTunes Connect, go to My Apps, select your app, then the version
- scroll down to App Review Information
- Enter details in the "Demo Account" section, and possibly additional details in the Notes section.

However, as others have pointed out, full App Store publication may not be the best option for such an app. You may want to consider Enterprise distribution (if used **only** by your own employees) or B2B/VPP distribution (which is through the App Store, but is not visible to everyone).

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem putting your app into the app store - there are quite some apps in the store now that require a login before they do anything, and are only of use for a selected audience. In the worst case you can add some general info views that are publicly accessible to show some value for everybody.

Enterprise distribution has its own hassles (and benefits), so if you don't have to go down that road I wouldn't.

In any case, provide the Apple Testing Team with some test login details.